# Calling Robocopy within python - Switches arent working?

Tags: python, subprocess

so from within my code I am calling the subprocess module 
    import subprocess

```
subprocess.call([r"robocopy", r"N:\\GIS\\Projects\\MarkTarrant_Data_Export", r"\\glenllsub1\\spatial\\LLS_Data\\Corporate_Data\\"])
```

This works fine and completes the copy !

But when I add the switch /S /E /MIR to the end it creates an error .

```
subprocess.call([r"robocopy", r"N:\\GIS\\Projects\\MarkTarrant_Data_Export", r"\\glenllsub1\\spatial\\LLS_Data\\Corporate_Data\\" /S /Z /MIR])


NameError: name 'S' is not defined
```

If I add theswitches to the end of the string

```
subprocess.call([r"robocopy", r"N:\\GIS\\Projects\\MarkTarrant_Data_Export", r"\\glenllsub1\\spatial\\LLS_Data\\Corporate_Data\\ /S /Z /MIR"])
```

It copies but creates switches as sub directories in the copied product not what I wanted.

Most likely a simple Noob errorI have overlooked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switches should be added as separate strings, separated by commas. Like this:

```
subprocess.call(
    ["robocopy", "N:\\GIS\\Projects\\MarkTarrant_Data_Export",
    "\\glenllsub1\\spatial\\LLS_Data\\Corporate_Data\\", "/S", "/Z", "/MIR"]
)
```